# Async function and promise taking too long to resolve

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have a function(**loadImageProfilePersonnel**) that create and load the image element attach to the DOM, the function returns a promise. I also have another function async function (**RenderHtmlPersonnel_Async**) that calls the promise. However the whole process takes too much time (2 seconds) for the image element to be displayed on the screen. I would appreciate if someone can tell me what to be improved in the code below.

```
function loadImageProfilePersonnel(profile)
{
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
  {

    const campus = profile.ProfileId;
    //const imageProfile = new Image();
    const imageProfile = document.createElement('img');
    if (profile.Picture !== '')
    {
        //imageProfile.src = '/Fundamental/ImageProfil/' + campus;
        imageProfile.setAttribute('src', `/Fundamental/ImageProfil/${campus}`);

    }
    else
    {
        //imageProfile.src = '/Content/assets/img/DefaultImageUser.jpg';
        imageProfile.setAttribute('src', '/Content/assets/img/DefaultImageUser.jpg');
    }

    imageProfile.onload = () => resolve(imageProfile);

    imageProfile.onerror = () => reject(new Error('Unable to load image for profile: ' + profile));

    const htmlMarkup =
        `<div class="widget widget-chart">

<div class="widget-header bg-inverse-dark">
             <h4 class="text-white">Informations du client</h4>  
</div>

<div class="widget-body">
              <div class="text-center m-b-30">
                  <img src="${imageProfile.src}" class="img-circle img-fluid" width="50" height="50">
              </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-parsley-validate="true" name="demo-form">
        <div class="form-group m-b-5">
            <label class="col-md-6" for="Nom">Nom : </label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
     <p id="Nom">${profile.PropertyValue1}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group m-b-5">
           <label class="col-md-6" for="Prenom">Prénom  : </label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
    <p id="Prenom">${profile.PropertyValue2}</p>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group m-b-5">
           <label class="col-md-6" for="Type">Type  : </label>
           <div class="col-md-6">
    <p id="Type">${profile.Type}</p>
           </div>
       </div>

      <div class="form-group m-b-5">
         <label class="col-md-6" for="SubCategory">Sous-Catégorie  : </label>
         <div class="col-md-6">
    <p id="SubCategory">${profile.subCategory}</p>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group m-b-5">
         <label class="col-md-6" for="Category">Catégorie  : </label>
         <div class="col-md-6">
    <p id="Category">${profile.Category}</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
      </div>`;
    $('.DetailsClientWifi').html(htmlMarkup);
    $('.DetailsClientWifi').css('display', 'block');
});
```

}

```
async function RenderHtmlPersonnel_Async(profile)
{

  const promise = loadImageProfilePersonnel(profile);
  const result = await promise;

  //console.log(result);

}


function AfficherUI(profileId)
{
    $.ajax({
           url: '/Observer/GetActiveClientsByFloor',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
                TypeId: '23-d'
           }
           success: function(response){
              profile = JSON.parse(response);
              if(profile.profileId === ProfileId){
                 RenderHtmlPersonnel_Async(profile);
              }
           }
   });
}
```

Comment: How long does the POST take? If that is the "slow point", then the code here does not matter.

Comment: how to check how long the POST take ?

Comment: Generally you can see response time in the 'network tab' within the chrome developer tools. @Xris

Comment: you better clone htmlMarkup, for a start., and use a const  with JS document.querySelector instead of jQuery

Comment: **you'd better clone this element, it would save you a lot of time already.**

Answer (score 0):

You created the `<img>` tag `imageProfile` and waits for it's `onload` event to resolve your promise but you **never** insert `imageProfile` anywhere in the document (you didn't do any `someElement.appendChild()`).

This means it literally takes **forever** for the promise to resolve because the `onload` event will **never** happen.

Comment: I do append at the end of the string template $('.DetailsClientWifi').html(htmlMarkup);

Comment: No. You are appending a string which has nothing to do with a live DOM object